# How can I do one executor FixedThreadPool wait for another executor SingleThreadExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executors

I have 3 tasks to do:

- First: Download htmlFile --------\ BOTH IN THE SAME EXECUTOR SEQUENTIALLY, IT'S WORKING OK.
- Second: Unzip htmlFile   ---------/
- Third: Download images ------> In another executor I need to download my images divided in 5 files, to do that I'm using FixedThreadPool(5), in other words 5 paralel downloads.

But when I click to download, my images download start without wait for htmlDownload finish, how can I do to my executorPool wait for my another executor singleThread??

Main Class:

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

            //Download HTML and Unzip Threads
            typeDownloaded = "html";
            DownloadUtil.downloadHtml(e, this, dns, port, uuid, filePathHtmlDownload, cookies, typeDownloaded);
            UnzipUtil.unZipHtml(e, this, filePathHtmlDownload, outputFolder, typeDownloaded);
            typeDownloaded = "images";
            DownloadUtil.downloadImages(e, this, dns, port, numImg, uuid, cookies, typeDownloaded);
```

My DownloadUtil class:

```
public class DownloadUtil {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginLocalServiceImpl.class.getName());

    public static void downloadHtml(Executor e, MainViewController controller, String dns, int port,
            String offlineUUID, String filePath, Map<String, String> cookies, String type) throws IOException {

        String urlHtml = "http://" + dns + ":" + port + Constants.TARGET_SERVICE_DOWNLOADFILES + offlineUUID;

        System.out.println(urlHtml);

        e.execute(new DownloaderTask(controller, urlHtml, filePath, cookies, type));

    }

    public static void downloadImages(Executor e, MainViewController controller, String dns, int port, int numImg,
            String uuid, Map<String, String> cookies, String type) throws SystemException, IOException {

        String filePath;
        String urlImages;

        if (numImg == 1) {
            filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents" + File.separator + "TargetApp" + File.separator + "TempImageDownload.zip";
            urlImages = "http://" + dns + ":" + port + Constants.TARGET_SERVICE_DOWNLOADIMAGES + uuid;
            e.execute(new DownloaderTask(controller, urlImages, filePath, cookies, type));

        } else {

            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numImg);

            for (int i = 0; i < numImg; i++) {
                filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents" + File.separator + "TargetApp" + File.separator + "TempImage" + i + "Download.zip";
                urlImages = "http://" + dns + ":" + port + Constants.TARGET_SERVICE_DOWNLOADIMAGES + uuid + "/?pos=" + (i);
                exec.execute(new DownloaderTask(controller, urlImages, filePath, cookies, type));

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you might need an ExecutorCompletionService.  They allow you to wait for jobs finishing in one pool so you can submit them into another one.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? Why does it matter to wait for the html download to finish before starting the image download?

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the submission of the image download tasks until the html download has completed, something like this:

```
    final ExecutorService htmlDownloadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final ExecutorService imageDownloadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    ...
    //Download HTML and Unzip Threads
    typeDownloaded = "html";
    final DownloaderTask htmlTask = DownloadUtil.downloadHtml(mainViewController, dns, port, uuid, filePathHtmlDownload, cookies, typeDownloaded);
    typeDownloaded = "images";
    final List<DownloaderTask> imageTasks = DownloadUtil.downloadImages(mainViewController, dns, port, numImg, uuid, cookies, typeDownloaded);

    // submit the html download escape
    htmlDownloadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // first run the html task
            htmlTask.run();
            // now submit the image tasks to run
            for (DownloaderTask imageTask : imageTasks) {
                imageDownloadExecutor.execute(imageTask);
            }

        }
    });
```

The helper functions have been changed to return the task instances, the task instances are then submitted to the appropriate executor service instances when it is appropriate. The html download task is submitted immediately to download the html, once the download completes the tasks to download the images are submitted. There are no thread blocking operations (CountDownLatch.await()) involved in this solution and so it should be more scalable/performant.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Guava has `ListenableFuture` that will execute other tasks upon completion of its task. The other way is to use a `CountDownLatch` to have the image download threads wait, but this occupies those threads while they wait.